# No sound on external monitor connected to MacBook Pro by HDMI to USB-C cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, audio, usb, hdmi

I have a 2020 Mac Book Pro which is connected to a Samsung monitor (U32R591CWN) using a USB-C (from the laptop) to HDMI (to the monitor) cable. While the monitor has built-in audio speakers, no sound is played when the monitor speaker is chosen. The volume bar is disabled too as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of the Sound pulldown menu on the Menu Bar with the Samsung monitor selected]

As another test, there is no sound either when the laptop is connected to a second external monitor (Lenovo LI2364d) simultaneously or individually.

Any explanation why this is the case?

Just FYI, here is the [user manual] of the Samsung display monitor (https://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201911/20191126134948185/BN46-01061A-02_CD_UR59C_WW_ENG_191126.0.pdf) of the Samsung external monitor.

Comment: **How** are you connecting the monitor? via HDMI, USB-C, etc? Please [edit] your question to add this information to further help you.

Comment: Alright, it is in the title though :)

Comment: Sorry, somehow I totally missed that.

Comment: Don't be sorry at all.